# Get template from inside class

Tags: c++, templates

Consider the following code:

```
template <template <int> class T>
struct B {
};

template <int N>
struct A {
    B<A> b;
};
```

This does not compile since `A` in `B<A> b` refers to the class `A<N>`, not the template. How can I get the template `A` from inside the body of `A<N>`?

Comment: +1 @T.C. Exactly, thanks! I can accept your comment as an answer if you post.

Comment: @par This is a clang [bug](http://llvm.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=9551), your code is valid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simplest way to bypass this issue, I think:

```
template <int N>
struct A {
    B<::A> b;
};
```

Although it's actually a very interesting issue because it seems that `B<A>` should work. From §14.6.1 [temp.local]/p1 of N3936:

> Like normal (non-template) classes, class templates have an
>   injected-class-name (Clause 9). The injected-class-name can be used as
>   a *template-name* or a *type-name*. When it is used with a
>   *template-argument-list*, as a *template-argument* for a template
>   *template-parameter*, or as the final identifier in the
>   *elaborated-type-specifier* of a friend class template declaration, it
>   refers to the class template itself. Otherwise, it is equivalent to
>   the *template-name* followed by the *template-parameters* of the class
>   template enclosed in <>.

So it seems like `B<A>` should be equivalent to `B<::A>`. GCC 4.8 [accepts](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/29a38078c40887a5) the code in the OP, though Clang 3.4 [doesn't](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3b432b686061480b).

Comment: Ah. I was using Clang.